# Batch file runs when executing my program on eclipse but the has issue when jar file is used

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar, runtime.exec

I am trying to extract an app from my android phone using java program. 
the code which calls my batch file is :-

```
public static void batch(String a,String b) throws InterruptedException
    {
    try {
        fchooser fc=new fchooser();
        String fg=fc.antd;
        String arg1=a;
        String userinp1=b;
       String dir=System.getProperty("user.dir");;


      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "this is batchrun and path is "+fg);


  Process pan =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\test1.bat",arg1,fg});

        pan.waitFor();
        ............
```

arg1 and fg are two  arguments which Ii pass to the batch file.

```
arg1= /system/app/Chrome
fg= C:\Users\sumeet.p1\Desktop\test2
```

The batch file is

```
cd %2
adb pull %1
pause
```

In eclipse, the program runs fine and extracts the file to the loaction specified in fg[in this case - C:\Users\sumeet.p1\Desktop\test2] but when i use a jar file of this program, the files are extracted to the folder where jar files are kept and not the location given in fg. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the `cd %2` line in your batch script. It might not be changing the directory as expected when you execute it from command line jar due to change in drive.

Please see if changing it to `cd /d %2` works as shown below:

```
cd /d %2
adb pull %1
```